# SetPixel and BitBlt

Tags: c++, mfc, blit, bitblt

what am i doing wrong? I want to draw a black line in the device context and then blit it to my MFC-application in C++:

```
void CmbmView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
  CRect WindowSize;
  GetClientRect(WindowSize);

  CDC *pMemDC = new CDC;

  pMemDC->SetPixel(0,0,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(1,1,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(2,2,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(3,3,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(4,4,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(6,6,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(7,7,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(8,8,RGB(0,0,0));
  pMemDC->SetPixel(9,9,RGB(0,0,0));

  pDC->BitBlt(0,0,WindowSize.Width(),WindowSize.Height(),pMemDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);

  delete pMemDC;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxzck32.aspx

Comment: Why don't just draw a line on the device that you are passed? `SetPixel` is jsut wrong for line drawing. And if you want to ask a question like this you do need to explain what went wrong.

Comment: I need to set pixel in the memory before blitting it to the output. The pDC->SetPixel function is too slow, so that you can see the image buildup.
What went wrong? I got a white screen.

Comment: Hans Passant gave you (part of) the answer. By the way, there is no need to use a pointer. The memory dc should just be a local CDC variable.

Comment: The example of Hans Passant doesnt help. There is a Bitmap loaded from system recources. But i need a function to draw own bitmaps with pixels and get them on the display.

Comment: Then you have to create a CBitmap of the required format, select it into the DC and then draw to it.